# Java: How to make two loggers write in different files (Logger)

Tags: java, logging, file-handling

I have 2 loggers in the same class, set up like this:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  
FileHandler fh;  

try {  
    // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter  
    fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/test/MyLogFile.log");  
    logger.addHandler(fh);
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);  
    // the following statement is used to log any messages  
    logger.info("My first log");  
} catch (SecurityException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

The second logger is set up the same way, just as `logger2` and `fh2` and `MyLogFile2.log`.

My problem is that whenever any logger logs, both files are written into, even though I only call one logger e.g. `logger2.log(Level.INFO, "msg2")`.

Why is that? Is it because both loggers are open at the same time? But I do not want to .close()/create them each time I use them. Any better solution?

Comment: Do log4j and java.util.logging.Logger work the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set another name for the instance here :

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");

Logger logger2 = Logger.getLogger("MyLog2");
```

Cause `Logger.getLogger("MyLog")` return an instance of the logger with name "MyLog" or create it if not exist

Comment: By the way, it's more conventional to name the logger with the class or package : `Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());`

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know that part mattered as it just looked like a name. Is there a naming convention for a second logger in the same package? `Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName() + "2");` ?

Comment: Since it is not conventional to have 2 logger in the same class, not at all :p